# Can SQL REPLACE function as a "find and replace" on both strings and substrings?

Tags: sql, database, t-sql

I have a database of boxes within boxes. Max nesting depth is 10, so each box could have up to 9 parent or child locations. One field contains the hierarchy of each box - i.e. for box DEF which is inside ABC:

`SELECT hierarchy from INVENTORY WHERE boxname = 'DEF'` returns "ABC -> DEF".

I now need to allow users to rename boxes. I'm trying to use SQL's REPLACE function to accomplish this, but it can't work on substrings as far as I can tell. I've tried:

```
update inventory
set hierarchy = replace(hierarchy, 'DEF', 'XYZ')
```

and this doesn't update the hierarchy to "ABC -> XYZ" like I'd expect

My hope is to use it as a "Ctrl+F find and replace" function, but **it seems like it can't do the following**:

1. Find all fields that contain the string, including as a substring.
2. Replace all occurrences across all fields for a given record.

Does anyone know if either of these are indeed possible?

I'm using TSQL.

sample data as requested:

**input**:

```
| name  | parent1  | parent2  | ...  | hierarchy         |
|  ---  |  ---     |  ---     | ---  |   ---             |
| DEF   | ABC      |          |      | ABC -> DEF        |
| JKL   | DEF      |  ABC     |      | ABC -> DEF -> JKL |
```

**output**:

```
| name  | parent1  | parent2  | ...  | hierarchy         |
|  ---  |  ---     |  ---     | ---  |   ---             |
| XYZ   | ABC      |          |      | ABC -> XYZ        |
| JKL   | XYZ      |  ABC     |      | ABC -> XYZ -> JKL |
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: added, let me know if you need more info

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it.

Comment: That's way too complicated. I'll just figure it out myself.

Comment: too complicated? Check out SQL Fiddle, they have this nice little link they call Text to DDL - where you paste in your text and they create the DDL and DML for you. Of course, you can always choose `script table as...` in SSMS. At the very least, we need to know the data type of the `hierarchy` column.

Comment: Aside: If you used a [surrogate key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) rather than a name scattered about then renaming wouldn't be an issue. You've also denormalized the table by storing the hierarchy as well as the parentage. You could use a _computed column_ if you need the hierarchy value frequently and it can be _persisted_.

Comment: I don't have control over anything else about the database. My job requires me to do what I described exactly. I can't change anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this isn't possible. SQL UPDATE with REPLACE does not function as a "find and replace". SQL does not have this functionality.